# User-specific IIS config

Tags: visual-studio, iis

Under `MyProject` > `Properties` > `Web` there is an option to "Apply server settings to all users" which stores the IIS config in `MyProject.csproj.user`.

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to set defaults. Meaning anyone who clones the project will have to customize these settings.

**Is there a way to set defaults when using user-specific IIS settings?**

I've attempted to use environment variables, but Visual Studio complains that it cannot create an IIS binding for `http://$(API_HOST):$(API_PORT)/`

Answer (score 1):

What is the setting you need to set? This is an important detail.
Most of the configuration could be setted in the web.config file infact this file has a "system.webServer" section dedicated to IIS Configuration.

example:

```
<system.webServer>
   <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
         <add value="Default.htm" />
         <add value="Index.htm" />
         <add value="Index.html" />
      </files>
   </defaultDocument>
   <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
   <httpErrors>
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\custerr" path="my_custom_404.htm" />
   </httpErrors>
   <security>
      <authentication>
         <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="IUSR" />
         <basicAuthentication />
         <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication />
         <digestAuthentication />
         <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication />
         <windowsAuthentication />
      </authentication>
      <requestFiltering>
         <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true" />
         <verbs allowUnlisted="true" applyToWebDAV="true" />
         <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="true">
            <add segment="Web.config" />
         </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
   <staticContent lockAttributes="isDocFooterFileName">
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="otect/stream" />
   </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/

Comment: Specifically, I'm trying to set `<IISUrl>http://10.211.55.4:1228/</IISUrl>` in the user config while retaining the default in the project config. This is nested under `ProjectExtensions`, see [here](https://gist.github.com/sliptype/15745fc61b0e0690cb6164d934ad656f).